# Sum of attributes values in model. Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a model that has many attributes, some are the sum of others. I would like to know if this is an efficient way to do it and if I should be aware of performance issues. The model is about 200 decimal fields and 30 fields summing the others...

This is what I have:

```
Class  FinancialDatum < ActiveRecord::Base 
  #---rest omitted

  before_save :totalize

  def totalize
    totalizable = [:total_1,:total2] #etc..
    totalizable.each do |t|
      unless totalizable_for(t).map{|m|self.send(m).present?}.include? false
        self[t] = (totalizable_for(t).map{|num| self.send(num)}).inject(0, :+)
     end
   end

    def totalizable_for(att)
    case att
      when :total_1
        [:debt_1, :debt_2, :deb_t_3]
      when :total_2
        [debt_4, debt_5]
      end
    end

end
```

EDIT:

Input and output is quite simple, user fills in `:debt_1 => 2, :debt_2 => 3, :debt_3 => 4` and the model should save `:total_1 => 9`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give sample input/output?

Comment: Sure, sample written. Thanks.

Comment: ` self[t] = (totalizable_for(t).map{|num| self.send(num)}).inject(0, :+) unless totalizable_for(t).map{|m|self.send(m)}.compact.empty?`

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky, but does this improve performance? In this case it seems more readable with unless..end